# How to find if two points A and B in an image file are connected by a straight or a zig zag line in python using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

**The Problem that I am working on:**

[image: Shape Info]

I am trying determine whether each of these shapes shown in the image above are connected to each other

**Work Done So Far:**

1) I have imported the image and used Graph based algorithms to determine that Shape A and C are connected by using intersection principle.

2) I am able to extract and trace the path from A to C

**Where I am stuck:**

I am not able to decipher the connectivity of A and B. My algorithm shows them unconnected.

I tried a rudimentary 8-nearest-neighbors to trace pixel path. But its too slow and in-efficient.

Is there a more efficient method to do this?

Comment: you can use findContours in the inverted image (255-img). If A and B are part of the same contour, they are connected.

Comment: Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum and how to ask them, (3) show your images and (4) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.